# How to relate any email with custom module data in Vtiger CRM?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I have created a custom module and also have integrated emails tab in Related  list.

Now I want to link any email with any entry from this custom module listing.

When I create(compose) any email and from that compose popup screen I am able to select my custom module option, but when i click on the "search" button to find the entry from listing (to which i want to relate that email), I find no listing for that custom module. However there are few entries available for that custom module.

So the issue is - The custom module listing shows no entries when try to select from compose email window.

Check the screenshots of the issue:

1. While composing email from : **Custom module >> Related tabs >> Emails >> Add Email**

[image: While composing email from : **Custom module >> Related tabs >> Emails >> Add Email**]

2. selecting related entity for email- **No listing is displaying for my custom module**

[image: selecting related entity for email]

Answer (score 0):

We resolved same issue on SalesOrder module. I have created on custom field email on Salesorder and update data for email field manually in this table also i have add **get_email()** function in salesorder.php file (copy from lead module).

[image: Compose email from SalesOrder Module]

get SalesOrder Module data which click on search button on pick list

[image: Get Customer list from SalesOrder module]

After this you can see the send email data in related list grid.

Comment: This might be working in your SalesOrder module as it was **in-built** module. In my case I have created a **custom module** called "Recruit" and i do have email field with data and also copied the **get_email()** function but didn't work for me.